# Get VML fillcolor="none" to work when using :fill

Tags: html, vector, vml

I have a VML question. I know... rare.

The problem is displaying an image using the "fill" element without a color behind it. I have repeating PNG patterns, so they are transparent in some places and I need to see through to underlaying elements.

So, here is the produced VML:

```
<fabCorners:shape style="CLIP: rect(1px 110px 168px 1px); Z-INDEX: 0; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" id=blockArea_26PatternVmlImage class="vmlElm vmlImage" op="0.71" coordsize = "109,167" coordorigin = "1,1" filled = "t" fillcolor = "none" stroked = "f" path = " m0,13 qy13,0 l97,0 qx110,13 l110,155 qy97,168 l13,168 qx0,155 l0,13 e">
   <fabCorners:fill class=vmlImageFill src = "/patternimages/patterns67_7_5.png" type = "tile" opacity = "46530f" position = "595f,390f">
   </fabCorners:fill>
</fabCorners:shape>
```

Even though the fillcolor is set to none, it still goes white.

I welcome any help, much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As whacky as it is, the solution lies in setting the fillcolor to none with js. For some reason, having fillcolor="none" in the markup isn't enough and doesn't work. But it you set fillcolor to none with js after page load, it works.

```
elm.fillcolor = 'none';
```